# How Do I Access the Payload of a Fetch Response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm sending a fetch request to a Google Script and want to know how to get the payload of the response.

Client-side Code:

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ type: 'proposal' }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
               }
 }).then( (response) => {
      console.log("success:", response);
 }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error:" + err);
 });
```

And on the server side (GAS) I have this:

```
function doPost(e) { 

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('It works!'); // Please add this.
}
```

The code successfully sends the fetch request and by looking at the Payload via Firefox Dev Tools I get the expected response ('It Works!').

However, in my log I'm getting the response object. How do I get access to the actual payload (the ContentService TextOutput returned by the script).

Comment: In the log I'm getting: 'success: ' then the object with the type, status, and header info but nothing with 'It works!' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Using Fetch" docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

The response from `fetch` is a response object, which includes a number of methods that you can call in order to get the parsed response. Each of them returns a promise, and you'll need to call the right one based on the type of data in the response.

For example:

```js
fetch('/url', {
  method: 'POST'
  ...
}).then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    ...here is the text response
  })
```

Or if your response is JSON:

```js
fetch('/url', {
  method: 'POST',
  ...
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    ...here is the JSON response
  })
```

Comment: Ahh... I understand. Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and great examples!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)

```
fetch(...).then(response => response.text()).then(text => console.log(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

I crafted this simple function which is ***awaitable*** as it returns a promise, thus it can run asynchronously.

```
let makeRequest = function(URL){
    return new Promise(function(callback){
        fetch(URL).then(function(res){
            res.text().then(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

Usage with **await**:

```
let text = await makeRequest('https://stackoverflow.com');
```

Old-school call:

```
makeRequest('https://stackoverflow.com').then(function(text){
    // Do stuff with text
});
```